# защита приложения через proguard для Android Studio

Tags: android, proguard

Приведите пожалуйста простейший пример защиты приложения через proguard для Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

включаете в `build.gradle` `minifyEnabled true`, и все. Часто вместе с разными библиотеками приводятся файлы конфигурации для `Proguagd`, их надо учитывать тоже.